# Vimrc: how to replace tabs with two spaces?

Tags: vim, indentation

This is weird that I used to make it work with my vimrc setting to replace every tab with two spaces, but it doesn't work now.

My old setting was like this:

```
syntax on
filetype on

set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
```

But it suddenly didn't work so I have tried this:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on 

set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
```

with no success(it forces 4 spaces).

How can I make it work to replace tabs with 2 spaces?

Comment: filetype plugins are overriding softabstop/shiftwidth/tabstop. You can see which one with `:verbose set sts? sw? ts?`

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks for your comment. But without filetype plugin, none of sts, sw, ts works. Any idea how to figure this out?

Comment: `filetype on` is sufficient to get the set commands overriden I believe. Does removing that line get them to go with two spaces? (If you really want this you can put the commands in the after directory)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this much

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set smarttab
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set shiftround

" converting tabs to space before writing hte a file 
set expandtab
autocmd! bufwritepre * set expandtab | retab! 2
```